# How to use gradle installed with android studio out of android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Please how can I use the Gradle shipped with android studio out of android studio? I tried running `gradle -v` on my ubuntu command line but it says the command is not recognized.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Sorry @Gabriele, its ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

For running gradle:

- Download gradle
- Unzip the zip file
- **add GRADLE_HOME/bin** to your `PATH` **environment variable**

Somenthing like:

```
wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-bin.zip
unzip gradle-2.5-bin.zip
export GRADLE_HOME="$HOME/yourGradleFolder"
PATH="$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin"
```

More [info here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html).

AndroidStudio donwloads the gradle distributions in this folder:

```
/home/xxxx/.gradle/wrapper/dists
```

If you would like to use the gradle wrapper inside the projects, it is enough to run

```
./gradlew xxxxxx
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but whenever I use `./gradlew xxxxx` , it re-downloads gradle and takes too long. Is there no where I can set the `GRADLE_HOME` so it works normally. In my `/home/.gradle/daemon` directory I have `2.2.1 2.4 2.5 2.8`. Does this mean I already have four different versions of gradle? I don't understand.

Comment: Yes. 2.2.1, 2.4, 2.5 and 2.8 are the different distribution that you have just downloaded with your wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

May you can install grade from

[Gradel download link](http://gradle.org/gradle-download/)

**Building and Running from the Command Line**
then Follow this link [Building and Running from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html)

please let me know if any issue.Thanks for asking.

Comment: I want to be able to use the gradle that comes with android-studio. I am using Ubuntu